# Question about Postgres with upper case TableNames - migrating from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, subquery

I am migrating a MySQL DB to Postgres and I might want to convert the table names to lowercase if it is going to be a huge problem.  The table is pretty small at this point.  The issue I am running into is with some queries having this sort of format.

I should mention that I am using Python and the psycopg2 PIP module to run the queries.

```
SELECT * 
from test t1 
WHERE created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) 
                    from test t2 
                    WHERE t1.UpperCaseTableName = t2.UpperCaseTableName ) 
 AND Completed = 0 
ORDER BY UpperCaseTableName ASC
```

I am aware that it is probably wise to avoid upper case names in Postgres for this very reason, but you apparently can double quote table names in queries if you want them to be case sensitive.  Postgres apparently otherwise assumes lowercase names.

The issue here is that trying various things with t1.UpperCaseTableName, like `"t1.UpperCaseTableName", t1."UpperCaseTableName", etc.`

always throws an error.

Is there even a way to convert that kind of MySQL query (works fine) into a form that will work in PostgreSQL?

NOTE:  Edit after reading comments:

Thank you, after playing around with it, this seems to work, although I may still want to just do away with upper case names:

```
SELECT *
from mwl m1
WHERE created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at)
  from mwl m2 WHERE m1."AccessionNumber" = m2."AccessionNumber")
AND completed = False ORDER BY "AccessionNumber" ASC
```

Comment: As long as you _create_ the tables and columns **without** any quotes, you can reference the tables and columns anyway you like: https://dbfiddle.uk/st6dHCde

Comment: I understand that.  Postgres apparently assumes lowercase table and column names if not double quoted.  The issue is that the tables and columns were created using quotes and some upper case letters.  So, just wondering if there is actually perform a query like the one above taking that into account ?  Otherwise, better to create them in lowercase from the get go.

Comment: Double quotes " work fine but without the error message we can't help you.